# Android Unit Tests - no such property: bootClasspath

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to execute a simple test case for Android following just announced unit testing support - http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support

After carefully following the walkthrough I'm trying to run `./gradlew test`.
I'm getting this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugGroovy'.
> No such property: bootClasspath for class: com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin
```

while using `com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0-rc1`.

Anyone else got stuck on that?

Comment: I'm getting the same error with a freshly checked out deckard-gradle and changing the gradle version to com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0-rc1

Comment: [This](https://github.com/nenick/AndroidStudioAndRobolectric) looks like a step in the right direction, but I can't get the JUnit run config to recognize the unit tests.

Comment: Forgot my Build Variants, now its working in the cloned project linked above. Still trying to incorporate into my project.

Comment: Can  you post your 2 (module and project) build.gradle files?

Comment: You may find further investigation in my own answer.

Comment: @WojtekErbetowski You should have said in your question that you're using the [groovy-android-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-android-gradle-plugin) instead of letting us guess that from the task name as your issue is very specific to that plugin.

Comment: @sschuberth true :-( I missed that very important part! Sorry

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that Groovy Android Gradle plugin (to have Groovy working on Android) isn't simply working with Android plugin in version `1.1.0-rcX`.

Here's a very interesting piece of code directly from `groovyx.grooid.GroovyAndroidPlugin`, version `0.3.5` (current latest, here's the [source](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-android-gradle-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/groovyx/grooid/GroovyAndroidPlugin.groovy#L123))

```
    def getRuntimeJars(Project project, plugin) {
    int index
    switch (getAndroidPluginVersion(project)) {
        case ~/0\.9\..*/:
            index = 0
            break
        case ~/0\.10\..*/:
        case ~/0\.11\..*/:
        case ~/0\.12\..*/:
        case ~/0\.13\..*/:
        case ~/0\.14\..*/:
        case ~/1\.0\..*/:
            index = 1
            break
        default:
            index = RUNTIMEJARS_COMPAT.size()-1
    }
    def fun = RUNTIMEJARS_COMPAT[index]
    fun(plugin)
}
```

and definition of `RUNTIMEJARS_COMPAT`:

```
private static List RUNTIMEJARS_COMPAT = [
        { it.runtimeJars },
        { it.bootClasspath }
]
```

So that API must have changed in Android Gradle between `0.9.x` and `0.10.0` (yeah, I know - those Google devs change everything there :[ ). So let's take a look at that problem making class in Android Plugin version `1.0.0`:

```
> javap -cp [path to proper jar] com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin:

public class com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin extends com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin implements org.gradle.api.Plugin<org.gradle.api.Project> {
...
public java.util.List super$2$getBootClasspath();
...
```

Yup! There's the method we need (coming from parent `com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin` class). Now there's nothing like that in version `1.1.0-rc3`. What's more, the API of `com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin` is completely changed, so it's not a matter of simple `if(version)` to fix that.

I guess there's no chance to have Groovy Android Gradle plugin working with Unit Tests (since `1.1.0`) until authors update the plugin.

Let's wait then.

Comment: Can you try with 0.3.6-SNAPSHOT and tell me if it works out of the box? Thanks!

Comment: Wasn't found in https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/codehaus/groovy/gradle-groovy-android-plugin/0.3.6-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml. Which repository do I need to add for Snapshots?

Comment: Thanks. It passes the compilation and works with 1.1.0, but there's no support for compiling Groovy test classes, therefore only Java tests work for now. It's still a big improvement!

Answer (score 1):

That Testing Support feature is experimental. That said maybe there is no quick solution to your issue or might be a bug.

However, I would dig deeper into this, reading the message:
This line `Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugGroovy'.` mentions the task, so I would go and figure what that task does. I suppose it's a delivered task. The error being that in that task there is a property missing `> No such property: bootClasspath for class: com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin`

So maybe try to find that task and make sure the bootClasspath property is set for the AppPlugin class.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, actually it helped me finding the cause

Answer (score 0):

Try to **upgrade** to the new version (**RC3**)

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0-rc3'
    // ..
}
```

You can also take a [look](https://github.com/nenick/AndroidStudioAndRobolectric) here in order to compare your current setup with a working example.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help