# Error:No such property: bootClasspath for class: com.android.build.gradle.LibraryPlugin

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

The moment I updated `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'` to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'`, I get this error message

> Gradle 'Project' project refresh failed
>
> Error:No such property: bootClasspath for class: com.android.build.gradle.LibraryPlugin

Anyone else having this issue and seems to know how to fix that? I've tried searching for `bootClasspath` in all of my gradle files, however I could not find anything.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Unit Tests - no such property: bootClasspath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28434161/android-unit-tests-no-such-property-bootclasspath)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I've figured it out why I got those errors:

First of all I was using the facebook-android-sdk, this one was easily fixed by using `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.22.0'` rather than downloading the repository manually from GitHub.

The other thing was that I was using [JCAndKSolutions android unit test plugins](https://github.com/JCAndKSolutions/android-unit-test). Simply removing that and using the [Android Studio to run the test works](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support) now.